# validates_uniqueness_of elasticsearch persistence

Tags: ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-ruby

How to `validates_uniqueness_of` for elasticsearch persistence. I have in a model with the include statement

`include Elasticsearch::Persistence::Model`

I want to include a uniqueness validation like 
`validates_uniqueness_of :username`

When I tried to initialize with a `new` function
`NoMethodError: undefined method validates_uniqueness_of for class`

Trace

```
undefined method `validates_uniqueness_of' for #<Profile:0x007fd83c2b8a10>
    from profile.rb:22:in `block in <class:Profile>'
    from /Users/a6001096/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/a6001096/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in `block in make_lambda'
    from /Users/a6001096/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:164:in `call'
    from /Users/a6001096/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:164:in `block in halting'
    from /Users/a6001096/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
    from /Users/a6001096/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `block in call'
    from /Users/a6001096/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `each'
    from /Users/a6001096/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
    from /Users/a6001096/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
    from /Users/a6001096/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_save_callbacks'
    from /Users/a6001096/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    from /Users/a6001096/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/elasticsearch-persistence-0.1.8/lib/elasticsearch/persistence/model/store.rb:51:in `save'
    from (irb):5



class Profile
  include Elasticsearch::Persistence::Model

  attribute :user_id
  attribute :username, String, mapping: { index: 'not_analyzed' }
  attribute :image_url

  validates_uniqueness_of :username

end
```

Comment: Can you paste the code where you have this? Also please share any stack trace that might be useful.

Comment: Added stacktrace  and the class with validates_uniqueness_of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without changing `Elasticsearch::Persistence::Model` I basically had to create my own validations since I didn't see any validations other than `presence`. In short, you have to make a `must search` to make sure it doesn't exist

```
profiles = Profile.search query:{bool:{must:[{match:{username: "xxxxx"}}]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

`validates_uniqueness_of` is a [class method of `ActiveRecord`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of)

Your `Profile` class should be defined using [elasticsearch-model](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model) like this instead

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Elasticsearch::Model

  attribute :user_id
  attribute :username, String, mapping: { index: 'not_analyzed' }
  attribute :image_url

  validates_uniqueness_of :username
end
```

Comment: I'm not using any regular db and using elasticsearch as persistence. Also according to doc here https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-persistence you can use validation `validates :title, presence: true`

Comment: what I'm asking here is what other validation I can use here, I don't seem to find anything else